# Room lines stills on my pcb and the top layers tracks are not displayed in 3D view, Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, routing, 3d

The fact is that I have routed. I would like to know how to proceed when this kind of thing happens when using altium.

The routed tracks can be seen perfectly in 2D view. But when click 3D view I can only see the buttom tracks.

I don't now if a strange lines are involved on this. The lines appears in 2D only if a zoom enought. But it can be seen without zoom it on 3D view.

I was trying to delete them, to select them and get information or even to look for belonging layer. But it seems not to be in any active one. They also can not be moved, neither being selected.

I put an image to show what I mean. This lines seems to look like an old lines when the room of components was created during the first schem importation. I think they are some kind of garbage from components room. [image]

How can I tourn off them? or how can the routed tracks of my top layer can be shown in 3D view? bottom tracks are visible in 3D view.

Comment: Select Tools -> Reset Error Markers. Or Run the DRC again.

Comment: @DrewFowler Thank you! it fixed my issue, leftovers lines has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, these lines that can be seen in your screenshots are DRC error markers showing unrouted connections. They are left over from when your parts were not placed or routed. You need to run the DRC again to remove them.

As for viewing top and bottom layer traces in 3D view, by default I believe the top layer soldermask is 0% transparent, meaning the tracks are not visible beneath it. The bottom layer soldermask, on the other hand, generally has some transparency (10-20% perhaps) so you can see the tracks. All you need to do is go into the View Configurations tab when in 3D mode and adjust the Top Solder Mask slider.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I click right button and go to layer transparency. I reduced the opacity from top solder mask layer, but tracks are not visible.